# systems of equations with exponents?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am building a website which will run on the equation specified below. I am in pre-algebra and do not have any idea how to go about this equation. my friends say it is a system of equation but I don't know how to solve those and no one I know seems to know how to do them with exponents. I was hoping that people on this site could tell me the answer to the problem. if you could explain how to do it not for me but for people in my situation with more experience that might make the question better for everyone ells looking into it. Thank you for your  answer!

Here is the system of equations:

$xy^5=8000$

$(xy^4)-(xy^3)=5000$

Comment: Have you tried it? IF so, can we see what you have done?

Comment: The two curves corresponding to each equation do not intersect anywhere. That is to say, you will end up with complex-valued solutions (these are not the usual numbers you are accustomed to). What are you trying to solve this for?

Comment: i have tide to learn how to solve a system of equation but i think i need a teacher to show me how and not my friends plus they dont even know if you would solve it as a systems of equation when it has exponents.

Comment: You solve it the same way as without exponents.  You just take one of the equations and solve for one of the two variables (in terms of the other) and then take that expression and substitute it into the second equation.

Comment: the equations can be changed to xy^5=8000 and (xy^4)-(xy^3)>5000 and the value will have to be where x and y are both positive and the x with the lowest value would be the best.

Comment: Just to make sure, you mean $x\times y^5$ and not $(xy)^5$, right?

Comment: yes i do mean that. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation tells you that $x=\frac{8000}{y^5}$.  Substituting that into the second equation you have $\frac{8000}{y^5}y^4-\frac{8000}{y^5}y^3=5000$ $$\frac{8000}{y}-\frac{8000}{y^2}=5000\\\frac{y^2}{1000}(\frac{8000}{y}-\frac{8000}{y^2}=5000)\\8y-8=5y^2\\5y^2-8y+8=0$$

But that gives imaginary roots, so either they never intersect or I did something wrong... Lemme check.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply second equation with $y^2$ then you get

$$xy^5 \cdot y-xy^5=5000y^2$$

Substitute $xy^5=8000$

$$8000y-8000=5000y^2$$

Divide with $1000$ and move all terms to left side

$$5y^2-8y+8=0$$

Since $d=b^2-4ac=(-8)^2-4\cdot5\cdot8=-96$ which is negative, there are no solutions.